# Meaning of Vacuum 10 days ago

Tags: postgresql

I have many tables which I already vacuumed last two days in addition the auto vacuum enabled even so when I run the below query I find that vacuumed tables which I worked on it didn't vacuum since 10 days ago so how can I handle it ?

```
select relname, n_dead_tup, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum from 
pg_catalog.pg_stat_all_tables where 
n_dead_tup > 0 order by n_dead_tup desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do anything. If there are not many `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s on a table, it doesn't require vacuuming often.

Examine the number of rows:

```
SELECT reltuples 
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'mytable';
```

and the number of dead tuples:

```
SELECT n_dead_tup
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE relname = 'mytable';
```

If the number of dead tuples exceeds 20% of the number of rows, autovacuum will be triggered.